# Oauth2 flow after access token is granted

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

For the Oauth2 flow, i understand that the first time user login with the credentials, the client app will send those credentials to Authorization Server(Google for example) for access token. If that credentials are valid, an access token will be granted to the client app and each time user do some activities on the client app (buying some online  items)

The access token after being granted will be stored on the client side, which is the user who provide the credentials local machine. Each time user make a request(Restful request for example) which contains embedded token in the header, the server will validate the JWT token to authenticate the user identity through checking whether the JWT is well-formed and the signing signature. Now here is part i don't quite understand, where does the secret key used to check the key embedded into the token come from ? Is it provided to the  server from google authorization server. Is it stored into the server database after access token is granted first time from the authorization. If that is true, the authorization server is not needed in the client server flow after granting the access token first time user login until the refresh token is needed ?

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens are signed with that key. Backend can check if signature is valid. This way you can ensure that token is not altered. Jwt tokens are transparent and it is easy to created them or add some claims (eg. add admin role). Only Authorization server can sign the token, because it has secret key. Anyone can check signature because you need public key to check signature and anyone can get it from Authorization server.

You can read more about how digital signing works [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9897/12192).

Comment: what do you mean by check the signature ? u mean to check whether the 'header.payload' in singature   are idential to header and payload individually ? If thats the case then secret key and public key are the same right since if the contents are valid then the token is signed by the server right ?

Comment: No. Signature is not in header and secret and public keys are not the same. Public and private keys are pair. Server uses private key to generate signature and it is kept secret. Public key is used to check signature and it is public, so anyone can get it and check if signature is valid. You can read more here:  https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/jwt/validate-jwt#check-the-signature